# How to extend or re-define or override jquery Inbuilt methods/functions like jQuery.fn.html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is what i am thinking of (this is not the actual function , just a prototype)

```
(function () {
var org = jQuery.fn.html;
jQuery.fn.html = function (e) {
    doSomethingHere(e);
    return org.apply(this, e);
};}());
```

So i want that every time the html function is called for any element my custom function should be called before setting that html.

Please Suggest .

Comment: Use `call` instead of `apply`, or change it to `apply(this, [e])` as apply expects an array, where call does not

Comment: @Taplar , this a prototype , and this is not functioning , even with your suggested correction. So i am actually looking the exact syntactic to use for jQuery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mtunbswL/  Works fine with my proposed change.